# Получение данных о пользователе

Tags: reactjs

Делаю приложение на ReactJS. Авторизацию сделал при помощи токенов (JWT). Когда пользователь входит в аккаунт, сервер отдает токены и данные юзера. Токены я сохраняю в localstorge-е. Но вот у меня возник вопрос. Сразу после авторизации данные пользователя есть. НО вот есть закрыть вкладку и открыть через какое-то время? данных о пользователе не будет, но будут токены. И вот сам вопрос. На каком этапе мне подгрузить данные пользователя, при этом проверив авторизован ли он (валидны ли токены).

Я пишу без redux-а. Создал UserStore как-то так:

```
class UserStore {

    constructor() {

        this._userData = null;

        this._accessToken = LocalStorage.retrieve("accessToken");
        this._refreshToken = LocalStorage.retrieve("refreshToken");

    }

    isUserAuth() {
        return this._userData != null && this.isAccessTokenPresent() && this.isRefreshTokenPresent();
    }

    getUserData() {
        return this._userData;
    }

    storeUserData(data) {
        this._userData = new UserData(data);
    };

    getAccessToken() {
        return this.isAccessTokenPresent()?this._accessToken:"";
    }

    isAccessTokenPresent() {
        return this._accessToken != null;
    }

    storeAccessToken(token) {
        if (UserStore.isTokenValid(token)) {
            this._accessToken = token;
            LocalStorage.store("accessToken", this._accessToken);
        }
    };

    getRefreshToken() {
        return this.isRefreshTokenPresent()?this._refreshToken:"";
    }

    isRefreshTokenPresent() {
        return this._refreshToken != null;
    }

    storeRefreshToken(token) {
        if (UserStore.isTokenValid(token)) {
            this._refreshToken = token;
            LocalStorage.store("refreshToken", this._refreshToken);
        }
    }

    static isTokenValid(token) {
        return typeof token === "string" && token.length > 0;
    }

}

export default new UserStore();
```

Хотел сделать глобальный объект на всё приложение.
(Если говнокод то пишите. буду учиться).

И вот на каком этапе мне подгружать данные?

Answer (score 0):

> И вот на каком этапе мне подгружать данные?

при каждом запросе к бэкенду добавляйте токен в заголовки запроса, например

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create(params);
axiosInstance.defaults.headers['X-AUTH-TOKEN'] = localStorage.getItem('_token');
axiosInstance.get(
    url,
    {
        params: data
    }
).then((response) => {
    // В ответе проверяете объект auth, переданный с сервера
    // содержащий данные:
    // аутентифицирован да/нет
    // обновлен ли токен да/нет
    // обновленный токен, если был обновлен
    // по этим данным вносите изменения в userStorage
}).catch((error) => {
    ...
});
```

на бэкенде, соответственно проверяете токен и в каждый ответ добавляете объект auth, содержащий:

- аутентифицирован да/нет
- обновлен ли токен да/нет
- обновленный токен, если был обновлен
- другие данные аутентификации

Comment: это все понятно. Один нюанс. Вот делать проверки о бэка придется при каждом запросе и если при каком-то запросе придет ответ что не авторизован то нужно сказать приложению выкинуть юзера на страницу авторизации. как это сделать?

Comment: Ну это уже вопрос не авторизации, а отслеживания событий. Если у вас глобальный объект, то не обойтись без redux, mobx или проброса состояния через React context. Или, если компонентов немного, то можно пробрасывать сквозь все объекты вниз props, содержащий данные юзера, а обратно прокидывать обработчик onUnauth

Comment: Понимаете ли в чем дело. У меня был опыт с redux-ом и мне это показалось ну уж говнокодерством каким-то. Столько файлов ради какой-то фигни. Из простого реакта приложение вздувается в два раза. за что?

А если без редукса, как-то можно сделать глобальные ивент? ведь запросы могут быть в любых компонентах.

Comment: Попробуйте mobx https://habr.com/post/282578/

Comment: @Tsyklop вам нужно написать middleware для axios, он решит ваши проблемы ("придется при каждом запросе" - я про эту строку)

Comment: @ИльяПаймушкин А есть ли пример этого?